# how to import javacardx.apdu in eclipse

Tags: package, javacard

I want to import `javacardx.apdu` and `javacardx.framework` in eclipse and use in applet in java card, how do this work? and how do I download .jar file to import.

thnaks

Answer (score 2):

You can find the JavaCard Development Kit [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/downloads/javacard-sdk-2043229.html).
The JCDK contains not only the APIs but also tools to help you build CAP files. You should read the documentation provided.

The jar file you look for is api_classic.jar and you should find it in the lib folder of the JCDK. You need to add it to your classpath so you can compile java card code.

Comment: Hi, I cant download jcdk form oracle. Do you have another way to I get jcdk 3.0.2 ? thanks

Comment: That's the official release site and that's where you should get it from. You shouldn't get another way to have it, you should instead fix your download problem.

Comment: I Know but in this site I should buy and I don buy it.

Comment: JCDK is free. I just downloaded JCDK 3.0.3.

Comment: I am so sorry, can you appload for me this file?

Comment: No, I can't. Follow the instructions on the site to download it.

Comment: Hi, I cant if I can do, dont want you because I live in Iran. but so thans for attendance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (usually) upload `.jar` files. You need to convert the class files within a package to a `.cap` file. This conversion is usually performed by the [JCDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/downloads/default-1970005.html) converter tool or a third party equivalent. It converts the byte code into Java Card compatible byte code and performs some early binding (using `.exp` files delivered with the various libraries).

You may of compile against the `api_classic.jar` found in the `lib` fo lderof the JCDK to find out if your code compiles. Note that the name of the `.jar` may differ for different versions of the JCDK - I've used the one for Java Card version 3, where the functionality has been split into the connected and classic API.

I strongly recommend you follow some tuturials and - of course - the book [**Java Card Technology for Smart Cards**: Architecture and Programmer's Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javacard/javacard-142511.html).

Comment: Note that Sun/Oracle has one of the most irritating web sites; please adjust links if they become out-of-date.